# How to enable a double dashed border?

Tags: html, css

When I type this:

```
   <style>
        .tavit{
            width:400px;
            height:300px;
            background-color:yellow;
            border:dashed; /*First I applied - border:dashed double (In order to get a double dashed border - but it didn't work for some reason*/
            border-style:double;
            margin:auto;
            font-size:medium;
            text-align:right;
        }
        .adom {
            color: red;
            font-size: xx-large;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
```

nothing works. Like it's even one or the other. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: You need to share a bit more, where are you using it? Is there any other css that overwrites it?...

Comment: Look at this. Some body has already solved this.
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/double-dotted-border/#post-82796

Comment: `border-style` property does not work that way. `double` property means double full line, and dashed means dashed. You can specify multiple values, but it will affect different sides of element:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

Comment: I don't think that would really work, `dashed` and `double` are different style, and what you are doing is you are overwriting the `border` by `border-style`

Comment: To begin with, when you use a short-hand notation such as `border`, you are limited in what you can put in your properties. Putting in 2 styles is definitely _not_ going to work. In any case, I don’t think that there is a simple solution. You will need to apply a trick such as using an alternative property which _looks_ like a border, or by wrapping your element inside another element, and applying a border to both.

Comment: @ivp Saw this, and tried, but it still didn't work. Seems like an outer div is the only solution?

Answer (score 16):

You can simply fix this with one `div`, you can use outline and border, then use `outline-offset` property

```css
.test {
  background:white;
  padding:15px;
  border:1px dashed #000;
  outline:1px dashed #000;
  outline-offset:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">see this</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `border-style as dashed double`,
But `border-style:double` property give `two border` but as `solid` lines, so you can use `pseudo selector` and declare border-style:dashed on both as below,

```css
 .tavit {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: yellow;
   border: dashed;
   border-style: dashed;
   margin: auto;
   font-size: medium;
   text-align: right;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .tavit:before {
   content: "";
   width: 94%;
   height: 280px;
   border-style: dashed;
   position: absolute;
   left: 2%;
   top: 8px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tavit">

</div>
```

Comment: Does not work properly in case of responsive screens

Comment: Yes. Because parent div width is declared in px and it will stop scaling after 400px in responsive screens. Thus if you use media query and make changes to parent div width, it will resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an outer and inner div and can give border to both of them.

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.outer {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Long long long text</div>
</div>
```